# max size of document in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have a question about population in mongoose library 
this is an example :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]  **// This field will probably reach a large size of ObjectIds from fans**
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

fans field will probably reach a large size of ObjectIds from fans , This can lead to a maximum document size of 16 MB .
Is there another way to overcome that obstacle?

Comment: Your question is related to modeling/designing the data. Some questions before deciding the structure of the entities/schema's. What is this relationship between a person, story and a fan? And, what is the number of each of these data likely to be?  How is the application going to use this data?

Comment: @prasad_ There is no other way to store fans data better than that

Comment: If you search the net a MB of text is approximately about 500 pages of text. 16MB is lot of text and lot of fan data per story. For querying purposes you have to know how many fans per story (likely to be). Also, you think of querying one document of 16MB size.

Comment: Well, then this method can lead to the maximum size of the document, because I do not know how many fans per story, perhaps as many as hundreds of thousands of fans , this means method will not work if the number of fans so much. 
Is there another way to store a large number of ObjectIds ?